# Запятая в предложении "На ее руке было кольцо(,) и больше ничего"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

Какой вариант правильный?

1. На ее руке было кольцо и больше ничего.
2. На ее руке было кольцо, и больше ничего.

Answer (score 2):

***На ее руке было кольцо, и больше ничего.***

1. Правило

**И БОЛЬШЕ НИЧЕГО**, *частица* (в конце предложения)
Частица «и больше ничего» употребляется в конце предложения (или части сложного предложения) в знач. «и всё», «и только» **и факультативно отделяется запятой** (реже – тире), в зависимости от интонации.

*Самый натуральный разбойник ты, **и больше ничего***. М. Шолохов, Тихий Дон. *На своих первых учеников он не смотрел с завистью, они просто учились **и больше ничего***... М. Пришвин, Кощеева смерть. *Видишь, что фашисты с городом сделали... Кирпич, **и больше ничего***... В. Некрасов, В окопах Сталинграда. ([Грамота.ру.](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_224))

2. Решение задачи (зависимость от интонации)

*На ее руке было кольцо, и больше ничего.* Запятая ставится, делается пауза.

Сравнить (при перестановке): ***На ее руке было кольцо и ничего больше.*** Здесь возможен соединительный союз И (нет паузы), но в то же время его можно рассматривать как присоединительный. ***На ее руке было кольцо, и ничего больше.***

3. Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

Она любит только свою красоту, **и больше ничего**! [И. Грекова. На испытаниях (1967)].

― А не надо никаких точек зрения! ― ответил странный профессор, ― просто он существовал, **и больше ничего.** [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)].

Вы мне не нужны, поэтому я вас люблю, **люблю и больше ничего**, ибо никакой корысти у меня к вам нет. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)].

...он сидел за столом строгий, чисто выбритый и пил чай, только **один крепкий чай и больше ничего.** [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 5 (1978)].